# SAS: Stuck in a loop even with changes made? Any pointers?

Tags: loops, sas

This is the code that I am using, I have tried changing a few things around but I think I am getting stuck in an endless loop.

```
DATA songs;
INFILE datalines;
INPUT City $ 1-15 Age domk wj hwow simbh kt aomm libm tr filp ttr;
ARRAY song (10) domk wj hwow simbh kt aomm libm tr filp ttr;
DO i = 1 TO 10;
IF song(i) = 9 THEN song(i) = .;
END;
datalines;
Albany    54 4 3 5 9 9 2 1 4 4 9
Richmond  33 5 2 4 3 9 2 9 3 3 3
Oakland   27 1 3 2 9 9 9 3 4 2 3
Richmond  41 4 3 5 5 5 2 9 4 5 5
Berkeley  18 3 4 9 1 4 9 3 9 3 2    
;
PROC PRINT DATA = songs;
TITLE 'WBRK Song Survey';
RUN;
```

Can you point out what is wrong here? I have already tried changing the DO loop by adding an incremental i.

```
DO i = 1 TO 10;
IF song(i) = 9 THEN song(i) = .;
i+1;
END;
```

but the result is the same. I am new to SAS although not new to programming. I am wondering if I am making a syntax error here. Either way, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Remove the extraneous code leaving only the import. Is your data being read in correctly?

Comment: yes, the data is being read in correctly. Not sure what you mean by "extraneous" code?

Comment: The array/if code is what I'm referring to. Separate it into two data steps and see if it works. If the data is being read in correctly it should.

Comment: Did you get this working?

Comment: Yes, apparantly it wasn't the code but my version of SAS which was hanging up on me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I suspected, there was an issue with your import statement, at least for me. The following code worked for me:

```
DATA songs;
INFILE datalines;
informat city $20.;
INPUT City $ Age domk wj hwow simbh kt aomm libm tr filp ttr;

ARRAY song (10) domk wj hwow simbh kt aomm libm tr filp ttr;
DO i = 1 TO 10;
IF song(i) = 9 THEN song(i) = .;
END;

datalines;
Albany    54 4 3 5 9 9 2 1 4 4 9
Richmond  33 5 2 4 3 9 2 9 3 3 3
Oakland   27 1 3 2 9 9 9 3 4 2 3
Richmond  41 4 3 5 5 5 2 9 4 5 5
Berkeley  18 3 4 9 1 4 9 3 9 3 2    
;
PROC PRINT DATA = songs;
TITLE 'WBRK Song Survey';
RUN;
```